# JPA / Hibernate - @OneToOne and @Where not working - so what now?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have successfully used a @Where clause in my @OneToMany relationship as follows:

```
 @OneToMany(mappedBy="reconciliationId")
 @Where(clause = "debit_type = 'TAX_RETURN'")
 private List<BtaReconciliation> taxPaidReconciliation;
```

The BtaReconciliation class is like this:

```
@Table(name = "bta_reconciliation")
public class BtaReconciliation implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "reconciliation_id")
private Long reconciliationId;

@Column(name = "debit_type")
private String debitType;

@Column(name = "credit_type")
private String creditType;
```

The thing is that the relationship should be a OneToOne rather than a ManyToOne.
The issue is when I change to this:

```
 @OneToOne(mappedBy="reconciliationId")
 @Where(clause = "debit_type = 'TAX_RETURN'")
 private BtaReconciliation taxPaidReconciliation;
```

it doesn't work.  The taxPaidReconciliation field is always null.

I did some searching online and I can see that @Where cannot be used with @OneToOne.

It simply won't work as above.

I have tried many other options but I simply can't figure out a way to get this to work.

Note:  The BtaReconciliation class should not be updated as there are many debit_types and I don't want to introduce changes there to support each debit_type.

I'm looking forward to hearing back on how to best resolve this issue.

Kind regards,
Fergal

Comment: If it's one-to-one relationship why do you need a clause? There is only one 'BtaReconciliation' matching foreign key 'reconciliationId'.

Comment: It is only one-to-one for the combination of reconciliationId and debit_type or credit_type.
That is BtaReconciliation can have two instances with the same reconciliationId but in this case they will not have the same value for debit_type / credit_type.... so it is unique for reconcilation and debit_type/credit_type.
So in the example above, the query for reconciliation_id and the debit_type=TAX_RETURN returns a single instance. Removing the TAX_RETURN will yield many rows..

Comment: This means there is no one-to-one link between this tables. If you want to do so consider using composite foreign keys which refer two columns which are id and type.

Comment: That's probably the right thing to do.  Do you know how to achieve this properly for the above example ? What should I do ?